json string is not converting to model
I have json response as below.
{"StatusCode":1,"Data":{"AndroidVersion":"1","IOSVersion":"1"},"Pager":null,"Error":null}

Now I want to convert to model where I have string extension as below.
func toJSON() -> Any? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
    return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
}

Model is as below
struct MobileSettingsModel : Codable {
    
    var StatusCode : Int?
}

Now I try to use as below.
let settingObject : MobileSettingsModel = response.toJSON() as? MobileSettingsModel ?? MobileSettingsModel()
"settingObject==\(settingObject)".printLog()

Why I get response as below
settingObject==MobileSettingsModel(StatusCode: nil)

I was expecting it to be
settingObject==MobileSettingsModel(StatusCode: 1)

Any idea what I am missing?

Does this answer your question? Simple and clean way to convert JSON string to Object in Swift

@tomerpacific : Which answer? By the way b.name = (json["name"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? "" is not what I wanted to try.. If I have 10 variables in object, I will die... who will manually converts everything...

You can never cast a dictionary to a custom type. Didn’t you get a compiler warning?

Finally I found.. I should have used JSONDecoder to decode...
Below is what works with me...
if let data = response.decryptMessage().data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let yourModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(MobileSettingsModel.self, from: data)
        print("JSON Object:", yourModel)
    } catch {
        print("Error parsing JSON:", error)
    }
}


toJSON() function returned a [String: Any] and this cannot be decoded. You may want to try:
func convert<T: Codable>() -> T? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
    return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}

let settingObject: MobileSettingsModel? = response.convert()
//Optional(MyAnswer.MobileSettingsModel(StatusCode: Optional(1)))

